# How to Convert speech into text using google shell

Tags: python, emacs, google-cloud-platform

I see this new video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gHP8bC27cMI
and did step-step, but on 1:04
have down this line:
Wrote /home/****/src/speech/cloud-client/quickstart.py
how can I paste this? as I can write only on the emac window.

after this I click
ctrl x
ctrl c
to save the emac and exit,
and then I write:
python src/speech/cloud-client/quickstart.py
and enter, but not getting any text.

please help me, thank you!

Comment: In my case I get this error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./python-docs-samples/speech/cloud-client/quickstart.py", line 53, in <module>
    run_quickstart()
  File "./python-docs-samples/speech/cloud-client/quickstart.py", line 24, in run_quickstart
    from google.cloud import speech
ImportError: cannot import name speech`, Do you get the same thing?

Comment: yes I got this error. have fix for it?

Comment: You should edit the question to include the error.

Comment: @Dave Why have you removed the error traceback?

Answer (score 0):

Well. According to this [issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/2515) they have not released a version of speech yet.

> @puneith We have not yet released a version of speech yet nor is it
>   yet included in the umbrella google-cloud package (notice it is not
>   listed on https://pypi.python.org/pypi/google-cloud/0.20.0).

Maybe you can try installing it directly by cloning the git repository.

> @gw00207 It's alread (partially) "implemented in google-cloud-python".
>   You can install from source and play with the current implementation:
>
> ```
> $ git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python
> $ cd google-cloud-python/speech
> $ python setup.py install
> ```

I tried it myself. It didn't work for me. But give it a shot from your side.